# ensuring randomly generated pairs are not the same through iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal here is to generate random pairings that are guaranteed to be unique through iterations(no two numbers are matched with each other more than once).

This is for a murder mystery party I write and host semi-annually, each number in my list would be replaced by a character name and then matched with another character to randomly generate two other characters that they have a motive to murder, and one that they would not murder(thus three iterations).

I'm not sure that my if statement at the end is actually doing anything, though the numbers seem okay. This is probably good enough as is for my purpose, but I'm trying to learn. Thanks.

```
import random

characters = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]#character list
print("list of all characters:")
print(characters)
print("")

i=1
while i <= 3: #loop three times
    random.shuffle(characters)#randomize list
    print("random character combinations", i, ":")
    for x in range(0,len(characters),2):
        pairing = [characters[x], characters[x+1]]
        print(pairing)
    i+=1
    if pairing == pairing: #ensure uniqueness? 
        continue
```

Sample output:

```
list of all characters:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]

random character combinations 1 :
[20, 2]
[15, 6]
[11, 18]
[22, 9]
[14, 8]
[12, 5]
[10, 16]
[7, 4]
[17, 21]
[19, 3]
[13, 1]
random character combinations 2 :
[6, 20]
[15, 17]
[19, 13]
[16, 14]
[21, 2]
[9, 10]
[7, 11]
[8, 4]
[18, 3]
[22, 5]
[12, 1]
random character combinations 3 :
[1, 2]
[13, 5]
[12, 18]
[9, 14]
[22, 3]
[7, 8]
[19, 4]
[10, 21]
[11, 15]
[6, 20]
[17, 16]
```

Comment: how will the output pairs look like?

Comment: output pairs are just lists of two pairs. not sure what you're asking.

Comment: can you show sample output ?

Comment: added the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a little confusing, but sounds like a fun puzzle.

To reframe your problem, I'm assuming you:

- Have to host a murder mystery party, and want to generate the targets for each attendee
- Want each attendee to have a different pair of people they might murder
- Want each attendee to have a certain person they will not murder

You would like to generate these automatically.

I'm not sure if this does what you want but I did it by creating a structure that will randomly select an item from its internal set, removes the item from its internal set and returns the item (i.e. it mutates itself destructively).

```
import random

class SelectsFrom:
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items

    def select_one(self, exclude=set()):
        if not self.items:
            raise Exception("No items remaining")

        available = self.items - exclude
        if not available:
            raise Exception("No items after exclusions")

        selected = random.sample(available, 1)[0]

        # remove the selected item from our list
        self.items = self.items - {selected}
        return selected
```

Then, by using three of these structures to manage three separate streams of choices.

```
names = ['Laure', 'Greg', 'Lashon', 'Allan', 'Saturnina',
         'Ruthie', 'Deedra', 'Shawana', 'Kathrin', 'Luna',
         'Sandie', 'Waylon', 'Virgilio', 'Karisa', 'Yvette',
         'Lamar', 'Brett', 'Delicia', 'Charles', 'Jeromy',
         'Eugenie', 'Lawanna'] # from http://listofrandomnames.com

while True:
    character_choices = []
    try:
        # Choose first murder target for character,
        # excluding own character from choices
        firstMurder = SelectsFrom(set(range(22)))
        # Choose second murder target for character,
        # excluding own character AND the first murder choice
        secondMurder = SelectsFrom(set(range(22)))
        # Choose a friend,
        # excluding own character AND the both murder choices
        wontMurder = SelectsFrom(set(range(22)))
        for i in range(22):
            first = firstMurder.select_one({i})
            second = secondMurder.select_one({i, first})
            friend = wontMurder.select_one({i,first,second})
            character_choices.append([i, first, second, friend])
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print("UNABLE TO FIND MATCHES, Starting again\n")
        character_choices = [] # Reset the choices we have found

# Print the successful choices
for (i, first, second, friend) in character_choices:
    print("Character [{}] will murder [{} or {}] but not [{}]".format(
          names[i], names[first], names[second], names[friend]))
```

It produces output like this (names for added flavour):

```
Character [Laure] will murder [Shawana or Virgilio] but not [Brett]
Character [Greg] will murder [Karisa or Waylon] but not [Saturnina]
Character [Lashon] will murder [Yvette or Lawanna] but not [Virgilio]
Character [Allan] will murder [Sandie or Eugenie] but not [Laure]
Character [Saturnina] will murder [Luna or Deedra] but not [Greg]
Character [Ruthie] will murder [Jeromy or Lashon] but not [Lamar]
Character [Deedra] will murder [Charles or Greg] but not [Allan]
Character [Shawana] will murder [Laure or Luna] but not [Waylon]
Character [Kathrin] will murder [Lawanna or Saturnina] but not [Luna]
Character [Luna] will murder [Delicia or Brett] but not [Jeromy]
Character [Sandie] will murder [Saturnina or Allan] but not [Kathrin]
Character [Waylon] will murder [Lashon or Kathrin] but not [Eugenie]
Character [Virgilio] will murder [Ruthie or Charles] but not [Sandie]
Character [Karisa] will murder [Kathrin or Delicia] but not [Yvette]
Character [Yvette] will murder [Lamar or Karisa] but not [Shawana]
Character [Lamar] will murder [Waylon or Shawana] but not [Ruthie]
Character [Brett] will murder [Allan or Yvette] but not [Lawanna]
Character [Delicia] will murder [Greg or Lamar] but not [Charles]
Character [Charles] will murder [Brett or Laure] but not [Lashon]
Character [Jeromy] will murder [Virgilio or Ruthie] but not [Delicia]
Character [Eugenie] will murder [Deedra or Jeromy] but not [Karisa]
Character [Lawanna] will murder [Eugenie or Sandie] but not [Deedra]
```

Comment: Note that there is a non-negligible chance of this raising an exception on any given run. You'll want to run the whole thing in a loop that retries until no exception is raised.

Comment: Yes, it definitely raises exceptions often.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but you interpreted correctly. Thanks for the insight. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To generate random unique pairs, you can do:

```
from itertools import combinations
import random

j =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
k = list(combinations(j, 2))
random.shuffle(k)
```

`k` is a list of 231 pairs.